# Optional unwrap fail, when outlets connected properly

Tags: ios, swift, null, option-type, unwrap

I'm developing simple app, where the user logins and can read articles from web. I recently added a code which sets a title at a second view while processing a segue, but my title at the second page is unfortunately nil. I have an object in storyboard connected properly to the variable in view controller, I checked this twice. I have no idea what to do, maybe I have unwrapped something not properly.

Code:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITabBarDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate, UIToolbarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var newsBar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet var accountBar: UITabBar!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        accountBar.delegate = self
        newsBar.delegate = self

        titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0x00B0E4)

        titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(16.0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let next: SectionViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SectionViewController

        switch segue.identifier! {
            case "hardwareSectionSegue":
                next.titleLabel.text = "Rubrika o hardwaru"

            case "softwareSectionSegue":
                next.titleLabel.text = "Rubrika o softwaru"

            case "webSectionSegue":
                next.titleLabel.text = "Rubrika o webových technologiích"

            case "programmerSectionSegue":
                next.titleLabel.text = "Rubrika o programování"

            case "mobileSectionSegue":
                next.titleLabel.text = "Rubrika o mobilních zažízeních"

            default:
                next.titleLabel.text = "Rubrika nenalezena"

                next.titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func unwindSegue(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
}
```

The exception occurs below the first case where I'm trying to assign a value to `next.titleLabel.text`. It says the `titleLabel` is nil, which it souldn't be.

The SectionViewController:

```
import UIKit

class SectionViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that it's caused by that type cast, but then how do I properly set the attribute, if the segue doesn't even know what type will the next view have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see what you're trying to do, but I'm afraid iOS doesn't let you do things that way. In your `prepareForSegue()` method you're trying to modify the view controller that is being created by setting a text value directly.

iOS lazy loads as much as it can, which means at this point in your program the label hasn't actually been created – it really is `nil`. If you put a breakpoint on that line you should be able to run `po next.titleLabel` in the debugger window to see `nil` come back. If you run `po next.view` first it will force iOS to create the view and all its subviews, at which point running `po next.titleLabel` again will work as you expect.

If you try creating a template Master-Detail Application project in Xcode you'll see the correct solution: set a property in your new view controller, then transfer that value to your label in `viewDidLoad()`.

**Summary**: When you're navigating from view controller A to view controller B, don't make A try to configure B's UI. Instead, send B the values it needs, and have B configure itself.

Comment: You say that I should pass it to another attribute of that class, but not an UI element?

Comment: Yes. You can assign to properties all you want to, just not UI elements. (This is only 99% true, but I'm not going to tell you the exception because it's a dirty, dirty hack! :) )

Comment: So thanks, I never thought that Swift is that lazy :)